# How to create Azure Cloud Service with Media Foundation feature automatically?

Tags: azure

I'm working on a WCF Service hosted on Azure Cloud Services that needs Media Foundation feature installed on that machine.

Normally, I would upload the service, remotely connect to it and install the feature every time I created a new machine.

Is there a way to avoid this and configure the Azure package so that it installs Media Foundation automatically?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

- Add a startup task to your role's definition in
  ServiceDefinition.csdef:

```
    <WorkerRole .... > 

        <Startup>

            <Task commandLine="startup.cmd" executionContext="elevated" taskType="simple"/>

        </Startup>

    <WorkerRole/>
```

- Add startup.cmd text file:

```
    PowerShell -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted .\startup.ps1
    EXIT /B 0
```

to your role's project and set "Copy to Output Directory" to "Copy always" for it.

- Add startup.ps1 text file:

```
    if ((Get-WindowsFeature Server-Media-Foundation).Installed -eq 0)
    {
        Add-WindowsFeature Server-Media-Foundation
        Restart-Computer
    }
```

to your role's project and set "Copy to Output Directory" to "Copy always" for it.

For me it was enough.

Answer (score 0):

For what it's worth, Media Foundation is now installed on **Windows Server 2016**. Specify [**Family 5**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cloud-services/cloud-services-guestos-update-matrix#family-5-releases) when deploying your cloud service.  I verified on the current configuration: `WA-GUEST-OS-5.15_201801-01`.

It is not installed on Server 2012 R2 (Family 4) which was probably the latest option at the time the question was posted.