# Microsoft Media Foundation in Azure Webapp

Tags: asp.net, azure, ms-media-foundation, cscore

I have been working on making a simple audio transcoder using CSCore in Asp.Net Core (targeting full framework). Whilst Working developing the proof of concept on my development machine it works like a dream however when I deploy it to azure it seems that there is no Media Foundation on these instances. When trying to instantiate the MediaFoundationEncoder I get a `DllNotFoundException` for `mfplat.dll`. I assume that there is no means to get this to work on an azure webapp? Any help or alternative solutions welcome if no simple solution is possible.

Comment: Does this help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22167471/how-to-create-azure-cloud-service-with-media-foundation-feature-automatically
?

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the help, does not seem to work looks like the Add-WindowsFeature is not a recognised cmdlet, function, script, or program. I ran this via Kudu command shell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either [wrap FFmpeg](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2163036/solid-ffmpeg-wrapper-for-c-net) (you can bring the portable `ffmpeg.exe` into your project, the App Service sandbox is fine with it), or hand off the [encoding job to Media Services](https://github.com/Azure/azure-content/blob/master/articles/media-services/media-services-dotnet-get-started.md#encode-the-source-file-into-a-set-of-adaptive-bitrate-mp4-files).

`ffmpeg.exe` running in the App Service sandbox:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/38672885/4148708

Comment: Thanks this worked pretty much well in Azure. Not sure how I will get waveform data now which is what the CSCore lib provided as well.

Comment: Looks like FFmpeg can export a PNG waveform https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Waveform, should be able to give you the actual values as well.

Comment: CSCore got a ffmpeg branch as well. It is still not released but decoding for windows platforms is already quite stable. You could quite easy add encoding.